# Specific feynman diagram

Tags: tikz-feynman, feynman, tikz-graphdrawing

I am very new to TeX and wanted to draw these diagram using Tikz-Feynman or some package.

Comment: search this site for tag `feynman`. you will find many examples. select one which will be close to what you like to have and tray to draw own one. if in this will suck, show us where. people here than will more easy to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The idea of this site is to provide assistance if you get stuck, not to convert screen shots to LaTeX code. In what follows, to give you a start I provide the first three diagrams because the ones with the blobs contain unreadable pieces. Notice that these do not rely on the graph libraries, i.e. can be compiled without lualatex. This choice is made because these diagrams do really not require any automatic layout routines, and the latter have caused problems in connection with the latest updates of lualatex and Ti*k*Z. Besides, arXiv does not support lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a) {$\Phi_{aA}$}; 
\vertex [right=3cm of a] (b) {$\Phi_{bB}$};
\diagram* {(a) -- [fermion,edge label'={$b$}] (b)}; 
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a) {$\phi_{aA}$}; 
\vertex [right=3cm of a] (b) {$\phi_{bB}$};
\diagram* {(a) -- [charged boson,edge label'={$b$}] (b)}; 
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (b) {$bB$}; 
\vertex [right=3cm of a] (c) {$cC$};
\path (b) -- (c) coordinate[midway] (v);
\vertex[above=1.5cm of v] (a){$aA$};
\diagram* {(b) -- [fermion,momentum'={$p$}] (v) -- [fermion,momentum'={$p-k$}]
(c),(v) -- [charged boson,momentum'={$k$}] (a)}; 
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As I said, your blob diagrams contain unreadable elements.

Comment: Just realized that the `b`s attached to the propagators should most likely be `p`s, and be attached to momentum arrows. You may tell whoever wrote the stuff on the blackboard to write `p`s in a way that they could be distinguished more easily from `b`s, and, what is probably more important, not to confuse arrows that indicate the charge flow with those indicating momentum flow. This is generally confusing, and will lead to inconsistencies in theories with Majorana fermions, say.